# Receive ImageButton inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following `Repeater` and `ImageButton`. The `Repeater` may have up to 750 of these `ImageButtons` (which works fine).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PokeSearchControl" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton OnClick="imgSearchResult_Click" BackColor="#333333" ID="imgSearchResult" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'/> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My codebehind:

```
protected void imgSearchResult_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   ChangePokemon(selectedImage, imgPoke1, labPoke1, labPokeName1);      
}
```

**`selectedImage`** would be the `ImageButton` which fired the `OnClick` event. How do I receive that Image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sender`](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s9p1.html):

```
protected void imgSearchResult_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedImage = sender as ImageButton;
    //Get selectedImage's properties here for example 
    string imageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    //Or do your stuff
    ChangePokemon(selectedImage, imgPoke1, labPoke1, labPokeName1);  
}
```